# How to get the program name in a fish shell script?

Tags: shell, fish

In bash, as in ruby, the program name is given by $0.  What is it in fish?  I can do the following if I have to:

```
set PROGRAM (ps --no-header -o args -p %self | egrep -o '\S+')[2]
```

But I'm sure the program name must be already available somewhere.  I could also set the program name in variable at the stub of each program, but that has maintenance problems.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get the same result as your command, it is the script filename you are looking for.

This information is not stored in a variable, but you get this by querying `status`.

```
basename (status -f)      # The name of the file
status -f                 # The full path of the file
```

More information:
http://fishshell.com/docs/2.0/commands.html#status

Comment: This doesn't work if the program name is differant than the file being executed. For example if the command is a function defined in config.fish or a symlinked file.

Comment: Please try not to define functions in your `config.fish`, instead, save your `functionName.fish` files to a location in your `$fish_function_path` and let fish lazily load the function when they're used for the first time.

Comment: `status -f` gives me the name of the file, not the full path.

Answer (score 6):

#### `fish` `3.x`

```
status current-command
```

See [*Deprecations* section](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/41b333117561794e8ba827c3561378f3366a8bcf/CHANGELOG.md#deprecations-1) of the `3.0` documentation.

#### `fish` `2.x`

Use `$_` for program name.

See [*Programmable title* section](https://fishshell.com/docs/2.0/index.html#title) of the `2.0` documentation.

Answer (score 4):

For `fish` use `$_` for program name.

Comment: Thanks.  I get nothing with $_.  There's a short reference to $_ in [link](http://fishshell.com/docs/2.0/index.html).  Also in [link](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/813).  Has something to do with window title, but it's not the actual program name.

Comment: Interactively, it's the name of the current command eg. for `echo $_` it' returns `echo`.  In functions, it's still the top-level interactive command you typed (e.g. `function f; g; end; function g; echo $_; end` and then you type `f`, it'll print `f`).  In non-interactive script it seems to be empty.  In any case, not what you want.

Comment: Is there a list of these special variable names anywhere? (Another would be `$argv`.) They're rather hard to Google for…

Comment: `$_` has been deprecated in fish `3.0.0` in favor of `status current-command` https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecations-1

Answer (score 1):

In [the docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/status.html#cmd-status) you can see that as of version 3.4.1 you can simply use

```
echo (status basename)
```