# Can a Fish script tell what directory it's stored in?

Tags: fish

So, I really like Fish - but I need some help with scripting.
  and in particular finding the path of the script being run.

Here is the solution for BASH
[Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Can anyone help me find the equivalent with fish?

Comment: Related: [How to get the program name in a fish shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975804/how-to-get-the-program-name-in-a-fish-shell-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `readlink -m` does not exist on macOS,

`DIR=dirname (realpath (status -f))`

Works on **macOS** and **Linux** at the same time.
This solution also has the benefit to work from an .sh file or even the command line.

Comment: you should provide a complete answer - provide the complete script code..  this also works from the command line btw. marked as favorite answer, TY

Answer (score 28):

`status --current-filename` will output the path to the currently executing script.

For more information on the status command, you can run `man status` or see the documentation at http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#status

Comment: That prints out the full path to the file. To get the full path to the directory the script is stored in, use `dirname (status --current-filename)`.

Comment: What if the file is being executed as a symbolic link? `status -f` will print the path of the link, not the actual file.

Comment: Answering myself: `dirname (readlink -m (status --current-filename))`

Answer (score 11):

In fish shell,

```
set DIR (cd (dirname (status -f)); and pwd)
```

is an equivalent to the BASH one liner

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

mentioned in [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in).

NOTE: fish shell will `cd` into that dir and stay there. Bash will `cd` but it stays contained in subcommand.

Comment: For the fish shell, to avoid changing the directory, how about: `set DIR (realpath (dirname (status -f)))` ?

Answer (score 5):

### File path

To get the full path of the script, use `status --current-filename`, or
`set FILE (status --current-filename)` to declare a variable.

### Directory path

To get the full path to the directory the script is stored in, use `dirname (status --current-filename)`, or `set DIR (dirname (status --current-filename))` to declare a variable.

**The equivalent to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in) is the following:**

`set DIR (dirname (status --current-filename))` is the equivalent

Comment: Using `dirname` directly will only give `.` if run from the same directory, or the directory name if run from another directory. Usually we want an absolute path.