# How to access remaining arguments in a fish script

Tags: fish

```
my-fish-script a b c d
```

Say you want to get the all arguments from the second argument onwards, so `b c d`.

In bash you can use `shift` to dump the first argument and access the remaining ones with `"$@"`.

How would you solve the problem using the fish shell?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In fish, your arguments are contained in the `$argv` list. Use list slicing to access a range of elements, e.g. `$argv[2..-1]` returns all arguments from the second to the last.

For example

```fish
function loop --description "loop <count> <command>"
  for i in (seq 1 $argv[1])
    eval $argv[2..-1]
  end
end
```

Usage

```
$ loop 3 echo hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

Comment: @AliGajani I did. It's a question I had that I couldn't find the answer to on SO, so I'm adding it now to help others. In fact, [SO encourages you to answer your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: welp the comment-ificition strips out all the whitespace making it unreadable... how are you supposed to... whatever, [here](https://gist.github.com/OwenAR/45b034152442951f3c34#file-gistfile1-txt). so you can't just use `set argv $argv[2..-1]` as a direct translation from bash, i mean. so i guess you're supposed to translate the logic to something different in "idiomatic fish"? unless there's some built-in function that actually has the same behavior?

Comment: @Owen_R It's still not clear what you're asking. Are you wondering how to simulate the behaviour of `shift` in fish? If so, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24101186/72321). Otherwise this discussion is off topic and you would be better off [asking a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: and how do you get the `$0` argument (the script's name)? `status -f`?

Comment: @xealits see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975804/how-to-get-the-program-name-in-a-fish-shell-script

Comment: keep in mind that indexes start at 1, i.e. `$argv[1]`

Comment: @maxpleaner thanks for the clarification , i was assuming thad indexes start at 0 and that was confusing me

Answer (score 28):

The behaviour of the `shift` command can be simulated with `set -e/--erase VARIABLE_NAME`.

The idea is to erase the first argument, then get the remaining arguments from the `$argv` list.

For example

```fish
function loop  --description "loop <count> <command>"
  set count $argv[1]
  set --erase argv[1]
  for i in (seq 1 $count)
    eval $argv
  end
end
```

Usage

```
$ loop 3 echo hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering, I [answered twice, because the answers are distinct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25210/253951). This way the community can decide which answer is better and can easily comment on the different answers.

Comment: I erase multiple times more like this method to potentially access remaining optional arguments more safely.  I do not do any explicitly counting of the array.  Nicely `set` does not fail on alternative 'accessing' a first indexed array argument.

Answer (score 12):

You could also use read which is more readable in my opinion:

```
function loop
  echo $argv | read -l count command
  for i in (seq 1 $count)
    eval $command
  end
end
```

This works better especially when you want to use more than the first argument.

```
echo $argv | read -l first second rest
```

Comment: @readers, `... | read -l ...` performs pattern matching over it's input to set the given variable names.
This won't work if the firsts argv value contain space -- not a risk here.