# Create Custom Fish Switches

Tags: bash, function, shell, fish

I am working on a fish shell function named quick( [see here](https://github.com/giannisl9/config/blob/master/fish/functions/quick.fish) ) and I would like to add some switches to it.

For example `quick -l` to list all pathLabels.

[Fish documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html) does not seem to provide such information.

My questions are,

- What is the best way to enhance a functions' functionality with switches in fish ?
- Is it possible to expand an existing command with new switches ?
- Does this relate to the similar topic for bash/shell ?

I have come across several related information out there like "[How do I parse command line arguments in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)" but have not found a clear and fish specific answer to those questions. Any help please, it will be appreciated !

Note: Checking `> functions alias` as an example, seems that just $argv is used within a switch statement.

Comment: More likely a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093649/how-to-access-remaining-arguments-in-a-fish-script

Comment: @AndyRay I have come across this and I was wondering if there is a better way for switches than accessing $argv and testing string equality. Switches are also treeted a bit different for completion, no ?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56511681/defining-new-fish-commands-in-a-script-and-parse-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getopt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/getopt.1.html). It's pretty verbose. Here's an example that just looks for `-h` or `--help`

```
function foobar
    set -l usage "usage: foobar [-h|--help] subcommand [args...]
                ... more help text ...
"
    if test (count $argv) -eq 0
        echo $usage
        return 2
    end

    # option handling, let's use getopt(1), and assume "new" getopt (-T)
    set -l tmp (getopt -o h --long help -- $argv)
    or begin
        echo $usage
        return 2
    end

    set -l opts
    eval set opts $tmp

    for opt in $opts
        switch $opt
            case -h --help
                echo $usage
                return 0
            case --
                break
            case '-*'
                echo "unknown option: $opt"
                echo $usage
                return 1
        end
    end

    switch $argv[1]
        case subcommand_a
            ... etc
```