# Defining new fish commands in a script and parse arguments

Tags: fish

Quick question. Is it possible to define new commands by scripting in fish? I want to program a new command along the lines of this:

```
newFunction --flag1 flag1Input --flag2 flag2Input then space delimited arguments
```

This new function would only by using already-defined commands in a way that functions do, I just want to be able to pass flags to this new function. Is this possible, or do I have to use another language like Python to create an executable for my hypothetical command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure! Just like in bash (or any interpreted language really) all you need to do is create a file, give it execute permissions and write your fish script in it!

- The first line of the file should be `#!/usr/bin/fish` (Modify that path if your fish installation is located elsewhere. You can check by calling `which fish`)
- Start writing your fish script, your arguments will be `$argv[1]`, `$argv[2]`... etc
- Give your script execute permissions: `chmod +x myscript`
- Put your script somewhere in your `$PATH` (for example `/usr/local/bin`) so that you can call it like other commands in the system.

Here's a useless example script that prints out the arguments you passed:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

for i in $argv
        echo $i
end
```

To parse the arguments you could use the [argparse](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#argparse) with [fish_opt](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#fish_opt).

What you do is: You specify what your flags are with `fish_opt` like so:

```
set -l options (fish_opt -s n -l name --required-val)
set options $options (fish_opt -s h -l help)
```

where `-s` is followed by the short form of your flag and -l is followed by the long form.

Then you use `argparse` to parse your arguments like this:

```
argparse $options -- $argv
```

Then you can check on your flags like this:

```
if set -q _flag_help
    echo "Haalp!"
    return 0
end
```

Notice that whatever your flag name is, it's gonna be set to a variable of the format `_flag_myflag`

Here's a complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

set -l options (fish_opt -s n -l name --required-val)
set options $options (fish_opt -s h -l help)

argparse $options -- $argv

if set -q _flag_help
    echo "Haalp!"
    exit 0
end

if set -q _flag_name
    echo My name is $_flag_name
    exit 0
end
```

Now let's call it:

```
$ myscript
$ myscript --help
Haalp!
$ my_script --name "Anthony"
My name is Anthony
```

Comment: How would one define flags to use with this script? By flags I mean named arguments on the command line.

Comment: is this still correct? it seems the `_flag_myflag` isn't working these days.

EDIT: Nevermind its always `_flag_short`

Answer (score 1):

See the [`argparse`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#argparse) builtin. That command makes it relatively easy to parse arguments in a fish function or script in a manner identical to how most programs parse CLI args. If your fish installation has put the standard fish functions in */usr/local/share/fish/functions/* then you can cd to that directory (or wherever they were installed) and `grep argparse *` to see how the standard fish functions use `argparse`.

Having said that I don't recommend fish as a general purpose scripting language for creating new "commands". I use fish as my interactive shell and have quite a few fish functions meant to be used as commands in an interactive fish shell. However, for general non-interactive scripting I use, and recommend using, a standard POSIX shell like bash or ksh.

Comment: Mind sharing why you don't recommend fish as a scripting language? In comparison to bash and ksh. Obviously bash is more popular, but that is not important to me. I find fish to be much more readable.